# WPF: set ListBoxItem select event in code

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Okey, in code (C#) I create some ListBoxItems and add them to a UniformGird that gets put in a Viewbox defined in XAML (and for practical reasons I can't define a ListBox on XAML).

When a ListBoxItem is Selected I need to fire an event that calls a method I have made.

In XAML I would just set an EventSetter that calls the method, but I'm not sure how I can do the same thing in C# code for ListBoxItem.

Comment: Did you try ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: @TareqB. I do not have a ListBox, I have a set of ListBoxItem in a UniformGrid.

Comment: I mean, Does not comes those ListBoxItem from a ListBox? Other way you can use the ListBoxItem.Select event if you dont have access to the ListBox, but then you will have to subscribe to all ListBoxItem, instead subscribing once with the SelectedIndexChanged. That is why I suggested it.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and try to look up the MVVM patern for WPF.  It's a little try at first, especially if you are used to WinForms, or some other code-behind heavy language. WPF is designed around the MVVM pattern (for the most part), and you wont's have to fight against WPF as much to get things working.  You will thank yourself later for learning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook up an event handler for the `Selected` or `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event:

```
ListBoxItem lbi = new ListBoxItem();
lbi.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += (se, ee) => { MessageBox.Show("do something..."); };
```